# Unity2D coloring a map

Tags: unity, c#, shaders

I have an image with a bunch of colored regions, with each region corresponding to a province in my game. Each province also has a nation owner, which has a respective color. I need to create a function that, when it is called, changes all pixels of a province's color on the first image and changes them to the owners's color on another image. Should I do this with shaders? A script?

Comment: How many regions and how many owners do you have? Is this data that changes frequently, or only once in a long while?

Comment: I have around 800 provinces, with about 50 nations (owners). This will be changed very infrequently.

Comment: Sounds like this would be better done with a script then. A shader would need a more complicated input setup to handle that many substitutions in a single pass, and if you're changing it infrequently then the overhead of doing it on the CPU and uploading to the GPU shouldn't impact you much. How have you tried doing this with a script so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure what I should do. Would it be most practical to make a script that checks every province using loops? Should I assign each province an array of coords, and change the pixels of the provinces that are being changed? How should I change the map, SetPixel or is there a more practical way?

Comment: All of that sounds like it could work. Try it the way that makes sense to you, then test it to see if it meets your needs. If it does, you're off to the races, and you don't need to wait on Internet strangers who might or might not have any better idea. If it doesn't meet your needs, then you'll have the ammunition you need to ask a detailed question, showing the code you're using and isolating the specific problem with it you need help overcoming.

Comment: How about using separate GameObjects for each region? Then you can manipulate on demand, ie you just change the color of the material from a script? You only have to convert your image to an array of smaller ones...